# Cocoapods - Tests don't run due to an 'early unexpected exit'-error

Tags: cocoapods

I have the following Podfile that includes a test target with a host application:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '11.2'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'AnimalHouse' do

  pod 'SnapKit'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'KingfisherWebP'

  # RxSwift
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
  pod 'RxDataSources'

  # Firebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'CodableFirebase'

  # Crashlytics
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'

  target 'AnimalHouseTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'RxTest'
    pod 'RxBlocking'
  end

end

target 'AnimalHouseTestsHostApplication' do
end
```

The test target builds, but the tests don't run and I get the following error:
`AnimalHouseTestsHostApplication.app (4820) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: The test runner exited with code 1 before checking in.))`

What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: This might be better suited to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Looks like the framework search paths was not included. can you follow the instructions in the test target build settings https://github.com/onmyway133/TestTarget#3-runpath-search-paths and try again?

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help.